# Find files and echo content on shell

Tags: linux, find, cat

Im trying to search all files within a directory by name and outputting the files' content onto the shell.

Currently I'm only getting a list of files

```
find -name '.htaccess' -type f


./dir1/.htaccess
./dir23/folder/.htaccess
...
```

But how can I **output the content** of each file instead. Thought of something like *piping the filename* to the `cat`-command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `cat` within the `-exec` predicate of `find`:

```
find -name '.htaccess' -type f -exec cat {} +
```

This will output the contents of the files, one after another.

Comment: I was wondering if it's even possible to output the filename right before each content

Comment: @pbaldauf Do: `find . -type f -name file.txt -exec sh -c 'printf "%s\n%s\n\n" "$1" "$(cat -- "$1")"' _ {} \;`

Answer (score 2):

See the manual page for `find` (`man find`).

> ```
> -exec utility [argument ...] ;
>          True if the program named utility returns a zero value as its exit
> status. Optional arguments may be passed to the utility. The expression must be
> terminated by a semicolon (``;'').  If you invoke find from a shell you may need
> to quote the semicolon if the shell would otherwise treat it as a control
> operator. If the string ``{}'' appears anywhere in the utility name or the
> arguments it is replaced by the pathname of the current file.  Utility will be
> executed from the directory from which find was executed. Utility and arguments
> are not subject to the further expansion of shell patterns and constructs.
>
> -exec utility [argument ...] {} +
>          Same as -exec, except that ``{}'' is replaced with as
> many pathnames as possible for each invocation of utility.  This behaviour is
> similar to that of xargs(1).
> ```

So, just tack on the `-exec` switch.

```
find -type f -name '.htaccess' -exec cat {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the `-exec` option of `find`.

```
find -name some_pattern -type f -exec cat {} +
```

Moreover, if all of them are plain text and you want to view them one by one, replace `cat` with `less` (or `view` from vim)

```
find -name some_pattern -type f -exec less {} +
```

To view & edit, use `vim` or `emacs` or `gedit` (at your own option)

```
find -name some_pattern -type f -exec vim {} +
```